# Microsoft Liquid: How to show the current quantum state

Tags: algorithm, f#, liquid, quantum-computing, qubit

I am programming quantum algorithms in Microsoft Liquid (F#). For debugging, it would be really nice to see what the current quantum state is.

I can use:

```
for q in qs do show "q[%d]=%s" q.Id (q.ToString())
```

where qs is my list of qubits, but this only works if the state is not entangled.
However, if it is entangled, is there a way to just show the current quantum state, e.g.:

```
ket = 1/sqrt(2)*[|00>+|11>]
```

Comment: I know very little about liquid or quantum computing, but I am intrigued by the use of a platform with roots in e-commerce platform for quantum algorithms — is there anything worth mentioning in your post about this technology choice?

Answer (score 3):

The Ket.Dump method will print a nicely formatted state vector to the console:

```
qs.[0].Ket.Dump()
```

See http://stationq.github.io/Liquid/docs/html/aecdd029-bf0a-3e8f-3c2b-348802584d85.htm and http://stationq.github.io/Liquid/docs/html/56e790bd-3150-17ca-adac-0b91ecf9ef7e.htm.